# what does "get to something" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am learning this course Stanford CS224N: natural language processing with Deep Learning.

The professor [is saying](https://youtu.be/mT5DW2DKqHA?t=1779)

> if you start getting into more technical and scientific English, it's
>   easy to get to a million words.

what does the phrase "get to" in "it's easy to get to a million words" mean?

does that mean "have", "generate", or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the that video, "getting into more technical and scientific English" is compared to the average physical dictionary that limits itself to about 250,000 words.

The point is that if you start listing words from more scientific or technical fields, such as medicine, your list will be much longer --- you will quickly pass 250,000 and have a list of a million or longer.

Your suggestion of "generate" is a reasonable synonym here. You could rephrase this sentence as "it's easy to generate a list of a million words in English if you include technical and scientific words."

Comment: If you are *listing* words, I would say that *get to* is synonymous with *reach*.